# How to use dynamic variable (varibale name contains a variable) in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, eval

i am stuck up in a simple case in mysql. i dont kown how to programme  a variable in another variable name.

```
@a='hello'
@hello='yes'
how can we get the value of @(@a) as 'yes' ;
```

MY case :

I try to import a txt file in mysql but the column are dynamic.

txt Ex

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6 COL7 COL8 COL9 COL10 COL11 COL12....
1    a    b     1    c    d
2    a1   a2    b1   b2   3   c1   c2   c3   d1     d2    d3
.....
```

the columns of letters are dynamic on depending the column of number value (1 or 2 or 3)

what i want to do is insert these data into a table in mysql

my solution is treate the dynamic part as a array and put it in one column of the table:

```
Number1      A       B        Number2    C               D
2            a1 a2   b1 b2    3          c1 c2 c3        d1 d2 d3
```

My sql command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'txt' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' (@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6,@col7,@col8,@col9,@col10,@col11,@col12,@col13,@col14,@col15,@col16,@col17,@col18,@col19,@col20) 

set Number1=@col1,

set A=(CASE @col1 WHEN '1' THEN @col2 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col2,',',@col3) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col2,',',@col3,',' ,@col4) END)

set B=(CASE @col1 WHEN '1' THEN @col3 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col4,',',@col5) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col5,',',@col6,',' ,@col7) END)"

set C ?
```

I want do it as :

```
set c=@col(1+@col1+@col1)
```

Because if i use case, i should write so many times, and for the next column C,  I SHOULD WRITE case of combination of col1 and the value of column NUMBER2

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: i am really blocked at this point....

Answer (score 0):

as iam bolocked in this point, so i spent one day to write a sql with a length of 31662
You even can not image what it sucks write all this by hand
:

```
sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE %s INTO TABLE cdr_data_test_1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' (@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6,@col7,@col8,@col9,@col10,@col11,@col12,@col13,@col14,@col15,@col16,@col17,@col18,@col19,@col20,@col21,@col22,@col23,@col24,@col25,@col26,@col27,@col28,@col29,@col30,@col31,@col32,@col33,@col34,@col35,@col36,@col37,@col38,@col39,@col40,@col41,@col42,@col43,@col44,@col45,@col46,@col47,@col48,@col49,@col50,@col51,@col52,@col53,@col54,@col55,@col56,@col57,@col58,@col59,@col60,@col61,@col62,@col63,@col64,@col65,@col66,@col67,@col68,@col69,@col70,@col71,@col72,@col73,@col74,@col75,@col76,@col77,@col78,@col79,@col80,@col81,@col82,@col83,@col84,@col85,@col86,@col87,@col88,@col89,@col90,@col91,@col92,@col93,@col94,@col95,@col96,@col97,@col98,@col99,@col100,@col101,@col102,@col103,@col104,@col105,@col106,@col107,@col108,@col109,@col110,@col111,@col112,@col113,@col114,@col115,@col116,@col117,@col118,@col119,@col120,@col121,@col122,@col123,@col124,@col125,@col126,@col127,@col128,@col129,@col130,@col131,@col132,@col133,@col134,@col135,@col136,@col137,@col138,@col139,@col140,@col141,@col142,@col143,@col144,@col145,@col146,@col147,@col148,@col149,@col150,@col151,@col152,@col153,@col154,@col155,@col156,@col157,@col158,@col159,@col160,@col161,@col162,@col163,@col164,@col165,@col166,@col167,@col168,@col169,@col170,@col171,@col172,@col173,@col174,@col175,@col176,@col177,@col178,@col179,@col180,@col181,@col182,@col183,@col184,@col185,@col186,@col187,@col188,@col189,@col190,@col191,@col192,@col193,@col194,@col195,@col196,@col197,@col198) set test=@col1,test1=@col2,test2=@col3,test3=@col4,test4=@col5,test5=@col6,test6=@col7,test7=@col8,test8=@col9,test9=@col10,test10=@col11,test11=@col12,test12=@col13,test13=@col14,test14=@col15,test15=@col16,test16=@col17,test17=@col18,test18=@col19,test19=@col20,test20=@col21,test21=@col22,test22=@col23,test23=@col24,test24=@col25,test25=@col26,test26=@col27,test27=@col28,test28=@col29,test29=@col30,test30=@col31,test31=@col32,test32=@col33,test33=@col34,test34=@col35,test35=@col36,test36=@col37,test37=@col38,test38=@col39,test39=@col40,test40=@col41,test41=@col42,test42=@col43,test43=@col44,test44=@col45,test45=@col46,test46=@col47,test47=@col48,test48=@col49,test49=@col50,test50=@col51,test51=@col52,test52=@col53,test53=@col54,test54=@col55,test55=@col56,test56=@col57,test57=@col58,test58=@col59,test59=@col60,test60=@col61,test61=@col62,test62=@col63,test63=@col64,test64=@col65,test65=@col66,test66=@col67,test67=@col68,test68=@col69,test69=@col70,test70=@col71,test71=(CASE @col71 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN @col72 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col72,',',@col75) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col72,',',@col75,',',@col78) END),test72=(CASE @col71 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN @col73 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col73,',',@col76) END),test73=(CASE @col71 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN @col74 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col74,',',@col77) END),test74=(CASE @col71 WHEN '0' THEN '0' WHEN '1' THEN @col75 WHEN '2' THEN @col78 END),test75=(CASE @col71 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE @col75 WHEN '1' THEN @col76 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col76,',',@col83) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col76,',',@col83,',',@col90) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col76,',',@col83,',',@col90,',',@col97) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE @col78 WHEN '1' THEN @col79 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col79,',',@col86) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col79,',',@col86,',',@col93) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col79,',',@col86,',',@col93,',',@col100) END) END),test76=(CASE @col71 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE @col75 WHEN '1' THEN @col77 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col77,',',@col84) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col77,',',@col84,',',@col91) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col77,',',@col84,',',@col91,',',@col98) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE @col78 WHEN '1' THEN @col80 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col80,',',@col87) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col80,',',@col87,',',@col94) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col80,',',@col87,',',@col94,',',@col101) END) END),test77=(CASE @col71 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE @col75 WHEN '1' THEN @col78 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col78,',',@col85) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col78,',',@col85,',',@col92) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col78,',',@col85,',',@col92,',',@col99) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE @col78 WHEN '1' THEN @col81 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col81,',',@col88) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col81,',',@col88,',',@col95) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col76,',',@col83,',',@col90,',',@col102) END) END),test78=(CASE @col71 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE @col75 WHEN '1' THEN @col79 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col79,',',@col86) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col79,',',@col86,',',@col93) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col79,',',@col86,',',@col93,',',@col100) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE @col78 WHEN '1' THEN @col82 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col82,',',@col89) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col82,',',@col89,',',@col96) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col81,',',@col88,',',@col95,',',@col103) END) END),test79=(CASE @col71 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE @col75 WHEN '1' THEN @col80 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col80,',',@col87) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col80,',',@col87,',',@col94) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col80,',',@col87,',',@col94,',',@col101) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE @col78 WHEN '1' THEN @col83 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col83,',',@col90) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col83,',',@col90,',',@col97) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col83,',',@col90,',',@col97,',',@col104) END) END),test80=(CASE @col71 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE @col75 WHEN '1' THEN @col81 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col81,',',@col88) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col81,',',@col88,',',@col95) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col81,',',@col88,',',@col95,',',@col102) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE @col78 WHEN '1' THEN @col84 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col84,',',@col91) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col84,',',@col91,',',@col98) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col84,',',@col91,',',@col98,',',@col105) END) END),test81=(CASE @col71 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE @col75 WHEN '1' THEN @col82 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col82,',',@col89) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col82,',',@col89,',',@col96) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col82,',',@col89,',',@col96,',',@col103) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE @col78 WHEN '1' THEN @col85 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col85,',',@col92) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col85,',',@col92,',',@col99) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col85,',',@col92,',',@col99,',',@col106) END) END),test82=(CASE test70 WHEN '0' THEN '0' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN @col83 WHEN '2' THEN @col90 WHEN '3' THEN @col97 WHEN '4' THEN @col104 END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN @col86 WHEN '2' THEN @col93 WHEN '3' THEN @col100 WHEN '4' THEN @col107 END) END),test83='',test84='',test85=(CASE test70 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col86 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col86,',',@col97) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col86,',',@col97,',',@col108) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col86,',',@col97,',',@col108,',',@col119) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col86,',',@col97,',',@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col86,',',@col97,',',@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130,',',@col141) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col93 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104,',',@col115) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137,',',@col148) END) WHEN '3' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col100 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144,',',@col155) END) WHEN '4' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col107 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129,',',@col140) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129,',',@col140,',',@col151) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129,',',@col140,',',@col151,',',@col162) END) END)WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col89 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col89,',',@col100) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col89,',',@col100,',',@col111) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col89,',',@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col89,',',@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col89,',',@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col96 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col96,',',@col107) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col96,',',@col107,',',@col118) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col96,',',@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col96,',',@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129,',',@col140) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col96,',',@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129,',',@col140,',',@col151) END) WHEN '3' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col103 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col103,',',@col114) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136,',',@col147) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136,',',@col147,',',@col158) END) WHEN '4' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col110 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col110,',',@col121) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132,',',@col143) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132,',',@col143,',',@col154) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132,',',@col143,',',@col154,',',@col165) END) END) END),test86=(CASE test70 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col87 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col87,',',@col98) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col87,',',@col98,',',@col109) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col87,',',@col98,',',@col109,',',@col120) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col87,',',@col98,',',@col109,',',@col120,',',@col131) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col87,',',@col98,',',@col109,',',@col120,',',@col131,',',@col142) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col94 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col94,',',@col105) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col94,',',@col105,',',@col116) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col94,',',@col105,',',@col116,',',@col127) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col94,',',@col105,',',@col116,',',@col127,',',@col138) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col94,',',@col105,',',@col116,',',@col127,',',@col138,',',@col149) END) WHEN '3' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col101 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col101,',',@col112) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134,',',@col145) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134,',',@col145,',',@col156) END) WHEN '4' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col108 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col108,',',@col119) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130,',',@col141) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130,',',@col141,',',@col152) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130,',',@col141,',',@col152,',',@col163) END) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col90 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col90,',',@col101) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col90,',',@col101,',',@col112) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col90,',',@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col90,',',@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col90,',',@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134,',',@col145) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col97 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col97,',',@col108) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col97,',',@col108,',',@col119) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col97,',',@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col97,',',@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130,',',@col141) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col97,',',@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130,',',@col141,',',@col152) END) WHEN '3' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col104 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col104,',',@col115) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137,',',@col148) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137,',',@col148,',',@col159) END) WHEN '4' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col111 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col111,',',@col122) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144,',',@col155) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144,',',@col155,',',@col166) END) END) END),test87='',test88=(CASE test70 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col89 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col89,',',@col100) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col89,',',@col100,',',@col111) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col89,',',@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col89,',',@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col89,',',@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col96 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col96,',',@col107) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col96,',',@col107,',',@col118) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col96,',',@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col96,',',@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129,',',@col140) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col96,',',@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129,',',@col140,',',@col151) END) WHEN '3' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col103 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col103,',',@col114) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136,',',@col142) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136,',',@col142,',',@col158) END) WHEN '4' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col110 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col110,',',@col121) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132,',',@col143) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132,',',@col143,',',@col154) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132,',',@col143,',',@col154,',',@col165) END) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col92 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col92,',',@col103) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col92,',',@col103,',',@col114) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col92,',',@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col92,',',@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col92,',',@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136,',',@col147) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col99 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col99,',',@col110) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col99,',',@col110,',',@col121) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col99,',',@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col99,',',@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132,',',@col143) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col99,',',@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132,',',@col143,',',@col154) END) WHEN '3' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col106 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col106,',',@col117) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col106,',',@col117,',',@col128) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col106,',',@col117,',',@col128,',',@col139) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col106,',',@col117,',',@col128,',',@col139,',',@col150) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col106,',',@col117,',',@col128,',',@col139,',',@col150,',',@col161) END) WHEN '4' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col113 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col113,',',@col124) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col113,',',@col124,',',@col135) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col113,',',@col124,',',@col135,',',@col146) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col113,',',@col124,',',@col135,',',@col146,',',@col157) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col113,',',@col124,',',@col135,',',@col146,',',@col157,',',@col168) END) END) END),test89=(CASE test70 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col90 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col90,',',@col101) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col90,',',@col101,',',@col112) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col90,',',@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col90,',',@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col90,',',@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134,',',@col145) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col97 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col97,',',@col108) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col97,',',@col108,',',@col119) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col97,',',@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col97,',',@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130,',',@col141) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col97,',',@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130,',',@col141,',',@col152) END) WHEN '3' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col104 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col104,',',@col115) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137,',',@col143) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137,',',@col143,',',@col159) END) WHEN '4' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col111 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col111,',',@col122) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144,',',@col155) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144,',',@col155,',',@col166) END) END)WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col93 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104,',',@col115) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137,',',@col148) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col100 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144,',',@col155) END) WHEN '3' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col107 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129,',',@col140) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129,',',@col140,',',@col151) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129,',',@col140,',',@col151,',',@col162) END) WHEN '4' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col114 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col114,',',@col125) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136,',',@col147) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136,',',@col147,',',@col158) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136,',',@col147,',',@col158,',',@col169) END) END) END),test90=(CASE test70 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col91 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col91,',',@col102) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col91,',',@col102,',',@col113) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col91,',',@col102,',',@col113,',',@col124) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col91,',',@col102,',',@col113,',',@col124,',',@col135) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col91,',',@col102,',',@col113,',',@col124,',',@col135,',',@col146) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col98 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col98,',',@col109) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col98,',',@col109,',',@col120) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col98,',',@col109,',',@col120,',',@col131) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col98,',',@col109,',',@col120,',',@col131,',',@col142) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col98,',',@col109,',',@col120,',',@col131,',',@col142,',',@col153) END) WHEN '3' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col105 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col105,',',@col116) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col105,',',@col116,',',@col127) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col105,',',@col116,',',@col127,',',@col138) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col105,',',@col116,',',@col127,',',@col138,',',@col144) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col105,',',@col116,',',@col127,',',@col138,',',@col144,',',@col160) END) WHEN '4' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col112 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col112,',',@col123) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134,',',@col145) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134,',',@col145,',',@col156) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134,',',@col145,',',@col156,',',@col167) END) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col94 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col94,',',@col105) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col94,',',@col105,',',@col116) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col94,',',@col105,',',@col116,',',@col127) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col94,',',@col105,',',@col116,',',@col127,',',@col138) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col94,',',@col105,',',@col116,',',@col127,',',@col138,',',@col149) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col101 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col101,',',@col112) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134,',',@col145) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col101,',',@col112,',',@col123,',',@col134,',',@col145,',',@col156) END) WHEN '3' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col108 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col108,',',@col119) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130,',',@col141) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130,',',@col141,',',@col152) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col108,',',@col119,',',@col130,',',@col141,',',@col152,',',@col163) END) WHEN '4' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col115 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col115,',',@col126) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137,',',@col148) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137,',',@col148,',',@col159) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137,',',@col148,',',@col159,',',@col170) END) END) END),test91=(CASE test70 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col92 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col92,',',@col103) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col92,',',@col103,',',@col114) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col92,',',@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col92,',',@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col92,',',@col103,',',@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136,',',@col147) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col99 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col99,',',@col110) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col199,',',@col110,',',@col121) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col199,',',@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col199,',',@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132,',',@col143) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col199,',',@col110,',',@col121,',',@col132,',',@col143,',',@col154) END) WHEN '3' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col106 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col106,',',@col117) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col106,',',@col117,',',@col128) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col106,',',@col117,',',@col128,',',@col139) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col106,',',@col117,',',@col128,',',@col139,',',@col145) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col106,',',@col117,',',@col128,',',@col139,',',@col145,',',@col161) END) WHEN '4' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col113 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col113,',',@col124) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col113,',',@col124,',',@col135) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col113,',',@col124,',',@col135,',',@col146) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col113,',',@col124,',',@col135,',',@col146,',',@col157) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col113,',',@col124,',',@col135,',',@col146,',',@col157,',',@col168) END) END)WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col95 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col95,',',@col106) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col95,',',@col106,',',@col117) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col95,',',@col106,',',@col117,',',@col128) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col95,',',@col106,',',@col117,',',@col128,',',@col139) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col95,',',@col106,',',@col117,',',@col128,',',@col139,',',@col150) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col102 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col102,',',@col113) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col102,',',@col113,',',@col124) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col102,',',@col113,',',@col124,',',@col135) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col102,',',@col113,',',@col124,',',@col135,',',@col146) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col102,',',@col113,',',@col124,',',@col135,',',@col146,',',@col157) END) WHEN '3' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col109 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col109,',',@col120) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col109,',',@col120,',',@col131) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col109,',',@col120,',',@col131,',',@col142) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col109,',',@col120,',',@col131,',',@col142,',',@col153) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col109,',',@col120,',',@col131,',',@col142,',',@col153,',',@col164) END) WHEN '4' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col116 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col116,',',@col127) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col116,',',@col127,',',@col138) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col116,',',@col127,',',@col138,',',@col149) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col116,',',@col127,',',@col138,',',@col149,',',@col160) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col116,',',@col127,',',@col138,',',@col149,',',@col160,',',@col171) END) END) END),test92=(CASE test70 WHEN '0' THEN '' WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col93 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104,',',@col115) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col93,',',@col104,',',@col115,',',@col126,',',@col137,',',@col148) END) WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col100 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col100,',',@col111,',',@col122,',',@col133,',',@col144,',',@col155) END) WHEN '3' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col107 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129,',',@col140) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129,',',@col140,',',@col146) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col107,',',@col118,',',@col129,',',@col140,',',@col146,',',@col162) END) WHEN '4' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col114 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col114,',',@col125) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136) WHEN '4' THEN CONCAT(@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136,',',@col147) WHEN '5' THEN CONCAT(@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136,',',@col147,',',@col158) WHEN '6' THEN CONCAT(@col114,',',@col125,',',@col136,',',@col147,',',@col158,',',@col169) END) END)WHEN '2' THEN (CASE test74 WHEN '1' THEN (CASE test82 WHEN '1' THEN @col96 WHEN '2' THEN CONCAT(@col96,',',@col107) WHEN '3' THEN CONCAT(@col96,',',@col107,',',@col118) WHEN '4' THEN ....."
```